# How can I hover over icons in Ubuntu Dock to see all windows of one application?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, navigation

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME 3. How can I show all open windows of a certain application using the sidebar (aka Ubuntu Dock)? Right now I have to right-click and select "all windows" to see my other open windows.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is done by `Super + W` under Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity. It provides you with a tile-style view of all open windows. As you are using Ubuntu 17.10 with the Unity-like Gnome environment, the key might be different. Under Gnome you may as well just pres `Super` to get a tile-like view of all open applications. BTW: Super = Windows Key

Answer (score 30):

I am not aware of any *window-preview-on-mouse-hover* feature, but you can activate previews of open windows on

- **Primary mouse button click** by running

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
  ```
- **<kbd>shift</kbd>+click** by running

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shift-click-action 'previews'
  ```
- **Middle mouse button click** by running

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock middle-click-action 'previews'
  ```
- **<kbd>shift</kbd>+middle mouse button click** by running

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shift-middle-click-action 'previews'
  ```

(To find out all possible options for an action, run

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

and so.)

---

As a side note, a [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) puts the application icons to the top bar (and provides an option to move top bar to bottom):
[image]

It also provides the window-preview-on-mouse-hover feature:
[image]
<sub>(source: [official GitHub page](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel))</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure if I should accept this as an answer as it isn't exactly what I asked? But this works just as well!

Comment: @James If I'm not mistaken the preview-on-hover feature you're looking for is not yet implemented. But I would recommend **not** accepting the answer so that in future if/when the feature is implemented others will be more motivated to post a new answer.

Comment: @James Dash to Panel provides preview-on-hover, see edit to my answer.

Comment: The **first one** is what most people are looking for. If you want to revert back, replace `previews` with `focus-or-previews`

Answer (score 10):

For Ubuntu 20.04

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action minimize-or-previews`

Comment: Got error: `(process:153488): dconf-WARNING **: 09:58:06.635: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 1):

Not your exact problem but did you try Dash to Dock ?

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

If you click on Behaviour you can select Show Window Previews when you click on an app in the dock, if you have two instances of the same app a preview of both will appear (instead of having to right click on an app)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSq8G.png