# 18.04 - How to enable right click dock icon to see windows open without having to click 'all windows'?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Is there anyway in Ubuntu 18.04 to right click a dock icon to get a list of the open windows from that program, right now I have to click 'All windows' to get to this list - which is hugely annoying as I do this hundreds of times per session.

Is there also a way to loop through the windows of the application by scrolling the mouse wheel over the icon?

These 2 features, along with the global menu and HUD are really killing my workflow with 18.04 since Unity has gone :(

Answer (score 1):

Feature 1, having the previews opened immediately upon right-clicking the application icon, is not available. Hopefully, a future version will allow for the previews to be immediately expanded on right-click. You can however change the left click, or shift+click or middle-click actions to show the previews, as outlined in the accepted answer of [this Askbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026442/17-10-how-to-hover-to-see-all-windows-of-one-application).

Feature 2, having the dock cycle windows when you scroll on the application's icon, can be enabled as per [this Askbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-ubuntu-dock) by changing a dconf setting:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'`

You may also change panel setting in dconf-editor, which is not installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Tweaks** and **Dash to Panel** from the Ubuntu Store. From Tweaks, enable the Dash to Panel extension and click on the gear icon to allow you to customize your panel to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Hey this is great! Didn't know dash to panel did this. I wish they'd implement it on hover instead of click.