# super + w used to open window manager on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 today. <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, used to open a window manager, I forget the name of it, and I could switch between windows (not to be confused with switching between applications with <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>).

Does anyone know how to do this with Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tap (press and release) <kbd>super</kbd> to get to the *Activities* overview with running windows.

Then use arrow keys to select a window and then <kbd>enter</kbd> to bring it into focus.

Comment: this will show the tile view for windows from all open applications. What if you only want to see the tile view of all the windows of just a single application.

Comment: @Ghos3t I'm not aware of any such option in GNOME 3, but you can activate options to see small previews for each application from Ubuntu dock (by clicking/shift+clicking/middle-clicking etc.) following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026442/17-10-how-to-hover-to-see-all-windows-of-one-application).