# preview windows from dock for switching between PDF documents

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Hi I have a problem which drives me crazy. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently and when I read some PDF documents and want to switch from one to another I always have to click 3 times: 1. rightclick on document viewer 2. "all the windows" 3. the PDF I want to select. This is horrible.
I have already tried different settings in dconf but nothing worked.
I want it to be like in Windows 10 where you hover over an icon and it gives you a preview of the windows. PLEASE HELP! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [17.10: how to hover to see all windows of one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026442/17-10-how-to-hover-to-see-all-windows-of-one-application) Alternatively, try this for a better workflow: [Switching between windows with scroll wheel on Ubuntu Dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-ubuntu-dock).

Comment: just left click the dock icon once and it will show all windows for that ap

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not hover, a single right click on the icon in the dock will pop up all windows for said application.

[image]

You can also use `alt+tab`to switch applications. Also, after the first alt+tab press, you will be able to navigate window selection using arrow keys and/or mouse.

Comment: Thank you! I already found the solution in the old thread :)