# Thumbnail preview in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, thumbnails

I think it will show thumbnails for folders by default in 18.04. But when I hover over the `files` icon, even with 2 folders open, I do not see a thumbnail. Not just folders, it does not show thumbnails for Firefox, Terminal or Gnome Clocks. I think it is safe to say that thumbnail preview is not available on my 18.04.

Is it normal ? Is there any method through which I can enable thumbnail preview ? Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1026442/739431 this may be useful.

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP . I was trying to avoid dash to panel. Looks like I have no choice now.