# How to show all windows side by side on icon hover (Like in windows)

Tags: gnome, gui, ubuntu-dock

I have just started using Ubuntu and wondering if I can show all windows on hover for an application.

I have attached the image of how it is now. eg I have 2 Chrome windows open and I have to click on the chrome icon and then click on all windows to be able to see them both and pick:

[image: Example image]

How can I make it like Windows where I can hover over Chrome icon and then the 2 windows appear without having to click anything.

Thanks,

Comment: Check this also -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026442/how-can-i-hover-over-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-to-see-all-windows-of-one-application?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) Gnome extension can do that.

[image: Dash to Panel Settings Screenshot]

[image: Dash to Panel Windows Previews]