# How to show all windows popup when clicking over ubuntu dock icons?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. How to show all windows popup when clicking over Ubuntu dock icons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hover over icons in Ubuntu Dock to see all windows of one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026442/how-can-i-hover-over-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-to-see-all-windows-of-one-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to enable preview and minimize on click

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action minimize-or-previews
```

I reffered
[How can I hover over icons in Ubuntu Dock to see all windows of one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026442/how-can-i-hover-over-icons-in-ubuntu-dock-to-see-all-windows-of-one-application)